# PHP DOM Text Replace

Tags: php, dom, xml-parsing

I need a little help in dynamically doing PHP DOM text replacement.  In my research, I found a snippet of PHP DOM code that looks promising, but the writer provides no method as to how it works.  The link to the code is: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php

So for, here's what I did in approaching the code as a newbie to DOM.

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadXML($myXmlString);
    
    $search = 'FirstName lastname';  
    $replace = 'Jack Daniels';      
    
    $newTxt = domTextReplace( $search, $replace, DOMNode &$doc, $isRegEx = false );
    Print_r($newTxt);
```

I would like the `domTextReplace()` return $newTxt.  How can I get it to do so?

Comment: you can't. that's built into PHP, but since that's just an extension of the regular DOM, you can query that dom tree for the "new" version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example to use that function:

```
<?php

$myXmlString = '<root><name>FirstName lastname</name></root>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($myXmlString);

$search = 'FirstName lastname';
$replace = 'Jack Daniels';

// The function doesn't return any value
domTextReplace($search, $replace, $doc, $isRegEx = false);

// Now the text is replaced in $doc

$xmlOutput = $doc->saveXML();

// I put xml header to display the results correctly on the browser
header("Content-type: text/xml");
print_r($xmlOutput);

// I copied here the function for everyone to find it quick
function domTextReplace( $search, $replace, DOMNode &$domNode, $isRegEx = false ) {
  if ( $domNode->hasChildNodes() ) {
    $children = array();
    // since looping through a DOM being modified is a bad idea we prepare an array:
    foreach ( $domNode->childNodes as $child ) {
      $children[] = $child;
    }
    foreach ( $children as $child ) {
      if ( $child->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE ) {
        $oldText = $child->wholeText;
        if ( $isRegEx ) {
          $newText = preg_replace( $search, $replace, $oldText );
        } else {
          $newText = str_replace( $search, $replace, $oldText );
        }
        $newTextNode = $domNode->ownerDocument->createTextNode( $newText );
        $domNode->replaceChild( $newTextNode, $child );
      } else {
        domTextReplace( $search, $replace, $child, $isRegEx );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
<root>
  <name>Jack Daniels</name>
</root>
```

Comment: I just tested the code and it works as expected.  What I was doing wrong was using `$doc->saveXML();` inside the `domTextReplace()`.  I just could not see how the `$doc` XML string would have got updated.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume the XML string got updated in the DOMNode class.  Is that correct?

Comment: Because the function taked `$doc` by reference (note the ampersand & in the function header), what means that if you change $doc object inside that function, it will remain changed outside aswell.
Please, consider to validate the answer :)

Comment: I now got it.  It now makes sense.

Comment: That's it! Well, not exactly but yes. The "`$doc` DOMNode class instance" got updated. Actually in the moment you make $doc->loadXML($myXmlString); you can forget the string, and then you always work on the object instance.